# Lua Modules visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

**I am losing my mind here,**

I am very new to Lua scripting and going through a few tutorials.

---

I am now learning about calling a module in Lua, but I have issues with running a **"request"** command.

namely (and what I have gathered from researching the problem for like 3 days to no avail)

I have set up my **package.path** ( and subsequently the repository that lua is using to search for module files) in a separate folder that I am calling on for this module. (Got that part!)

---

What I am not understanding however is how to add to the path.package in a way that will search for a file outside of that given repository, and doing this using **Vs Code.**

---

Again, I am still very new to both lua as well as vs code. But so far I have been following along and understanding it pretty well, but I seem to have hit a road block.

---

"Any help here would be hot!" - Jar jar

---

P.S

Here is a look at the error I am getting in the terminal, but I am fairly sure it is just explaining what I already mentioned about how Lua is searching for the module in a different location than I have set it too:

---

---

---

> Executing task: lua54 C:\Users\Me\Desktop\LearningLua\Lua-Course_#2\Lesson_16\modules.lua <

lua54: ...\Desktop\LearningLua\Lua-Course_#2\Lesson_16\modules.lua:1: module 'myModule' not found:

```
    no field package.preload['myModule']
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\lua\myModule.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\lua\myModule\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\myModule.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\myModule\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\..\share\lua\5.4\myModule.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\..\share\lua\5.4\myModule\init.lua'
    no file '.\myModule.lua'
    no file '.\myModule\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\myModule.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\..\lib\lua\5.4\myModule.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\myModule.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\Me\lua\myModule54.dll'
    no file '.\myModule54.dll'
```

stack traceback:

```
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...\Desktop\LearningLua\Lua-Course_#2\Lesson_16\modules.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

---

### The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c lua54 C:\Users\Me\Desktop\LearningLua\Lua-Course_#2\Lesson_16\modules.lua" failed to launch (exit code: 1).

### so again just wanna know how to set it up to search through the new folder.

Here is an image of my edit to vs code lua path setting.... (maybe this will help understand how lost I am here)

[Me Lost in The Coding Woods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1fHz.png)

Comment: `package.path = package.path..[[;C:\your\path\?.lua]]`

Comment: thank you for your response! can I ask a dumb question?

what are the '?' indicating. That is also throwing me off.

also I don't know how to implement the info you gave me just now into adding a new path in a separate folder. (loading a module) 

but I thank you anyway for your reply

Comment: `?` is usual question mark. It should be inserted instead of filename.  After changing `package.path` invoke `require("myModule")`

Comment: okay first off! you're awesome! so thank you for that.

I have it set up now in my code before running the lua program and it works fine.

do you know if it is it possible is vs code to add this to .json or something so it runs in all files within a project directory?

thank you for helping me

Comment: Try defining `LUA_INIT` environment variable.  Place your code about package.path inside this env var.  It will be executed on Lua VM start.